# naming issue with enums inside the class

Tags: c#, enums

I'm designing a namespace called `ScriptLib`. Inside `ScriptLib`, I have a base class `Script` with a few derived classes, including but not limited to `SPoint` and `SWhiteSpace` and a standalone class `ScanGrid`.

```
namespace ScriptLib
{
    public enum ScriptType { Point, WhiteSpace }
    public enum BoundaryPointMode { FourPoints, TwoPoints }
    public enum GridSizingMode { EqualInterval, EqualQuantity }

    public class Script
    {
        public ScriptType ScriptType { get; set; }
        //other properties and methods etc.
    }

    public class ScanGrid
    {
        public BoundaryPointMode BoundaryPointMode { get; set; }
        public GridSizingMode GridSizingMode { get; set; }
        //other properties and methods etc.
    }

    public sealed class SPoint : Script
    {
        public new ScriptType ScriptType => ScriptType.SPoint;
        //other properties and methods etc.
    }

    public sealed class SWhiteSpace : Script
    {
        public new ScriptType ScriptType => ScriptType.WhiteSpace;
        //other properties and methods etc.
    }

    //more classes derive from Script and all use ScriptType
}
```

`Script` and all its derived classes use `ScriptType`, and `ScanGrid` use the other two enums.

At the moment I place them inside the namespace but outside the classes. However, I feel I pollute the namespace this way, since the enums are not used by all classes. Please note that I only started to work on this namespace; more classes and enums will come.

However, if I place `ScriptType` inside the `Script` class and the other two in `ScanGrid`, it leads to the naming problem. I'd like to keep the names for properties, so I need to come up with new names for the enums. Do I name them like: `ScriptTypeType`, `BoundaryPointModeType` and `GridSizingModeType`? To me they do not only read badly but also seem too long, especially the ones for `ScanGrid`. Imaging the following code:

```
scanGrid.GridSizingMode = _equalInterval.Checked ?
    ScanGrid.GridSizingModeType.EqualInterval:
    ScanGrid.GridSizingModeType.EqualQuantity
```

Is it common to put the enums directly under the namespace even though they are not used by all classes in the same namespace?

Is there a good way of naming the enums and referring to them if I place them inside the classes?

Comment: You can (and in my opinion: should) create different files for each enum and class to keep it clean. This way it will not look 'polluted'. You can still have all of them in the same namespace.

Comment: It's a concept from your domain, having it in an appropriate namespace doesn't "pollute" it. As you have noted yourself this is an opinion-based question, thus voting to close.

Comment: @BartoszKP didn't know opinion based post are not allowed here. I probably also misunderstood the meaning of "polluting" something.

Comment: @Anthony Here you can find the guidelines on what is on-topic on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here is a quote from [nested types usage guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Do not use public nested types as a logical grouping construct; use
>   namespaces for this.
>
> Avoid publicly exposed nested types. The only
>   exception to this is when variables of the nested type need to be
>   declared in rare scenarios such as subclassing or other advanced
>   customization scenarios.

So basically it's a bad idea to put enums into class just to remove them from namespace. Also it's bad idea to expose nested enums via public members - you have *public* properties of nested enum's type. Now back to your question:

> However, I feel I pollute the namespace this way, since the enums are
>   not used by all classes.

When you are declaring some enum (or another type) in some namespace, it does not mean this enum should be used by all classes in that namespace. E.g. there is enum `DayOfWeek` in `System` namespace. And it's not used by all classes in `System` namespace. It's not even used by most of these classes.

> However, if I place ScriptType inside the Script class and the other
>   two in ScanGrid, it leads to the naming problem.

You have this naming problem, because you are using nested types as they are not supposed to be used. But you can simplify your life a little with C# 6 [using static directive](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/namespaces.md#using-static-directives). :

```
using static ScriptLib.Script;
```

This directive imports static members *and nested types* contained directly in a type declaration. Thus you will be able to use nested types without name qualification:

```
scanGrid.GridSizingMode = _equalInterval.Checked
    ? GridSizingModeType.EqualInterval
    : GridSizingModeType.EqualQuantity
```

Comment: So the solution is obvious: leave the enums outside classes. Thank you. Your answer is a massive help.